# WordPress Missing a temporary folder

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have some issue for a word-press  `Missing a temporary folder`., im already work on my site ,today i got a big mistake all of root folder  file are deleted ,again reinstalled and config my db after my website is work but cant upload theme and image , how to fix that , im tried to fix that issue using lot of tutorial but not work   , please help me to fix that issue

Im tried to this tutorial but not work ([this tutorial  not work](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-manage-temporary-folder-missing-error-while-uploading-media.html) )

Thanks

Comment: "Im tried to this its not work" - Which bit didn't work? SSH or some kind of panel? If panel, have you asked the support people?

Comment: Sir, yeah im open the  tickets for that issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up the file permissions on your server.

- All directories should be 755 or 750.
- All files should be 644 or 640.
  Exception: wp-config.php should be 440 or 400 to prevent other users
  on the server from reading it.
- No directories should ever be given
  777, even upload directories. Since the php process is running as the
  owner of the files, it gets the owners permissions and can write to
  even a 755 directory.

Use recurrent setup the permissions, for example with FileZilla FTP.

More details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case, you need to use FTP. Connnect from FileZilla or by SSH. You need to change permission rules for your project folder (or for your uploads folder). If you have linux server, you can use `chmod -R 755 project_folder_name` command from terminal SSH. You can connect to remote server by SSH by such command `username@host_address -p host_port`. All premission rules you can find [here](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc).

If you have no knowledge to fix it, you can easily ask your hosting support to do this.