# how can i solve 'temporary folder not found' error during WordPress uploads

Tags: php, wordpress

I just re installed WordPress and I was trying to upload the file but the upload fails saying temporary folder not found
I tried other solutions from the web about adding a temp folder in wp-content folder
And adding a line of code in wp-config.php to define location of the temp folder but still no success
I'm installing WordPress through cpanel on windows 8.1
Your help will be grately appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Missing a temporary folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621884/wordpress-missing-a-temporary-folder)

Comment: you could add more details like the underlying OS on whom you are installing WP, WP version or a screenshot with the error. How are you installing WP? manually or do you use  a "button" from your host provider?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a folder if it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)