# "A temporary folder is missing" error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, storage

I have a troubleshooting with wordpress Version 5.7.2 hosted in OVH dedicated server.

When I try to upload an image I get this error ==> A temporary folder is missing

I have checked my disk space, I get 8.8Go available.

My PHP.INI SETTINGS ==>

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Missing a temporary folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621884/wordpress-missing-a-temporary-folder)

Comment: No I tried the solution, it didn't work

Comment: There might be more existing questions and answers over at [wordpress.se].